# How to create dynamic databases in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

We are going to create a backed that will have lots of users and our design principle is to create a separated database for each user, this way we have more control if we have to roll back or anything...

Is it possible to have a users database and the create new databases on the go (and connect to them depending on the user) in Laravel?

If so, how do we do that?

Comment: possible but a database for each user?

Comment: I think it is a good design to keep each user totally separated, we want to create a really complex backend that will have a lot of data for each user so thats why we would like to keep them totally apart

Comment: That doesn't sound sensible. If you have a separate database for each user then you would need to have separate code base for each database. That makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('createdb', [HomeController::class,'createDB']);



<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function createDB()
    {
        try{
            $new_db_name = "DB_".rand()."_".time();
            $new_mysql_username = "root";
            $new_mysql_password = "";

            $conn = mysqli_connect(
                config('database.connections.mysql.host'), 
                env('DB_USERNAME'), 
                env('DB_PASSWORD')
            );
            if(!$conn ) {
                return false;
            }
            $sql = 'CREATE Database IF NOT EXISTS '.$new_db_name;
            $exec_query = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
            if(!$exec_query) {
                die('Could not create database: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
            }
            return 'Database created successfully with name '.$new_db_name;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

No Tnx My Pleasure......!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).